# IOS SDK 7.0 + MKDirections + calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler

Tags: ios, xcode, mapkit, directions, ios7

i am working on demo app of MapKit updates in IOS SDK 7.0.

I am trying to find route b/w two places via IOS SDK 7.0. As if you know, apple allow to get direction within app and not need to use external API from IOS SDK 7.0.

And When i am calling calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler, getting exception. My code and my error as below.

```
[direction calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler:^(MKDirectionsResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                NSLog(@"%@",[response description]);
                NSLog(@"%@",[error description]);

            }];
```

Error:

```
[CLPlacemark isCurrentLocation]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9c34ab0
```

Can any one help me to solve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue. Actually, i have passed `CLPlacemark` instead of `MKPlacemark` in my direction request.

Thanks